# Unity JS to C# conversion - Incomplete list of public variables in Inspector

Tags: unity, c#, javascript

I'm trying to convert a javascript file to a C# script for Unity, mostly because the rest of my workflow is in C#, and I'm much more comfortable with C#.  In this case, it's an audio controller script.

The .js looks like this:

```
var audioClips              : AudioClips[];                     // Array of single use audio clips
var audioLoops              : AudioClips[];                     // Array of loops

class AudioClips{
    var name            : String;
    var audioClips      : AudioClip[];
    var volume          : float             = 1.0;
    var volumeBySpeed   : boolean           = false;
    var minVolume       : float             = 0.2;
    var pitchBySpeed    : boolean           = false;
    var minPitch        : float             = 1.0;
    var maxPitch        : float             = 1.0;
}
```

and the editor looks like this:

[image]

My C# script looks like this:

```
public class AudioClips : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string       _name;
    public AudioClip[]  audioClips;
    public float        volume          = 1.0f;
    public bool         volumeBySpeed   = false;
    public float        minVolume       = 0.2f;
    public bool         pitchBySpeed    = false;
    public float        minPitch        = 1.0f;
    public float        maxPitch        = 1.0f;
}

public class AudioController_SFB_C : MonoBehaviour {

    public AudioClips[] audioClipsArray;                        // Array of single use audio clips
    public AudioClips[] audioLoopsArray;                        // Array of loops
```

and the editor looks like this:

[image]

The C# code doesn't reflect all of the public variables.  Interestingly, even if I comment out the `public AudioClip[]` section and the code that relies on it, my inspector looks the same.  I'm thinking maybe there a scoping issue or a strong-typing issue that I'm missing, but I can't seem to see it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your missing data from the included instance of `AudioClips`. UnityScript is a little more flexible, in that it already serialises these things for you. In C#, you need to specify that you intend to use serialisation, with the `[System.Serializable]` attribute.

As a side note, you have included the inheritance of `AudioClips : MonoBehaviour`. We need to expressly note inheritance in C#, where UnityScript correctly assumes. However, this particular class is being used to store data, not to represent a mono behaviour. We should not inherit from `MonoBehaviour`.

Simply remove the inheritance and add the attribute to your class, as follows, and it should display in the editor.

```
[System.Serializeable]
public class AudioClips
{
    public string _name;
    public AudioClip[] audioClips;
    public float volume = 1.0f;
    public bool volumeBySpeed = false;
    public float minVolume = 0.2f;
    public bool pitchBySpeed = false;
    public float minPitch = 1.0f;
    public float maxPitch = 1.0f;
}
```

Comment: That was 99.5% of it - thank you.  Can't even believe I missed that.  The other part was then not leaving it as a `MonoBehavior`.  I had initially set it as a `MonoBehavior` because it was the only thing that made it show up at all.

Comment: @Jesse Williams, of course. I completely missed that, myself. Updating my answer, thanks for the amendment.